# Login with ADFS on AD with one way cross forest trust

Tags: active-directory, cross-domain, single-sign-on, adfs

We have one domain with trust (not-transitive) to two other domains. The base domain user can login without any problems, but the users from other domains cannot.

We get exception from ADFS like this:

> The Federation Service encountered an error during an attempt to
>   connect to a LDAP server at {trusted domain}.
>
> Additional Data  Domain Name: {trusted domain}  LDAP server hostname:
>   {trusted domain dc} Error from LDAP server:   Exception Details:   A
>   local error occurred.
>
> User Action   Check the network connectivity to the LDAP server. Also,
>   check whether the LDAP server is configured properly.

After reserching we found out, it's the one-way trust problem. The problem is, we don't have any posibility to change the trust configuration or to set up other ADFS on trusted domains.

Is there some possibility to get it to work? Maybe some work around solution?
Is it possible to change the FormSignin page, search the user manualy with DirectoryServices and manualy create the token?

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to do it if you keep your ADFS service account in the trusting domain (in a one-way trust scenario).  You would need to allow that account to be able to query LDAP in the trusted domain, which would usually mean a two-way trust.

Absent that, you may try to setup use an ADFS service account from the trusted domain.  Of course, this would only work for one of your domains (unless the two other domains have trusts between themselves).